# sqlCeDataAdapter.update, Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6, sql-server-ce-3.5

**strong text*
hi all
this is my code :

```
for(int i =0 ;i<listView1.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            if(listView1.Items[i].Checked)
            {
                DataRow dr = ds.Tables["EXPORT"].Rows[i];
                dr.BeginEdit();
                dr["MODE_PAIEMENT"] = "cheque";
                dr["SOLDE_RESTANT"] = "0";
                dr.EndEdit();
                //dt.AcceptChanges();
                //ds.Merge(dt);
                try
                {
                    connexion.da.Update(ds, "EXPORT");
                }
                catch (Exception x) {
                    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
                }
```

i have that erreur : Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows. What shoud i do !! !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do what it says, and set the `UpdateCommand` Property of the `DataAdapter` with your SQL `UPDATE` statement.

[SqlDataAdaptor.UpdateCommand property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand();
updateCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET col=@val";

 connexion.da.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;
```